# Need help to resolve cyclic dependency problem

Tags: go

I am working on one project at my company where I need to add a new interface and it's implementation to the existing code. While I did that, I came across a challenging situation where I am hit with cyclic dependency issue.

Here are further details:
Project directory: test-cyclic-dependency
Existing code is in File1: test-cyclic-dependency/model/state/model.go

```
package state

import ("test-cyclic-dependency/model")

type CollectionByCollectionName struct {
    CollectionName string
    imOfTypeInModel model.STRING
}
```

I need to define a new interface Search in File2: test-cyclic-dependency/model/search.go

```
package model

import (
    "test-cyclic-dependency/model/state"
)

type Search interface {
    Search(keyword string) state.CollectionByCollectionName
}

type STRING string
```

This code resulting into cyclic dependency error as below:

```
# go build model/state/model.go 
package command-line-arguments
    imports test-cyclic-dependency/model
    imports test-cyclic-dependency/model/state
    imports test-cyclic-dependency/model: import cycle not allowed
```

Could someone help me to address this issue? Would there be a way to resolve it keeping the code organisation the same?

Comment: Do you really need the `type STRING string` ? because I think if you wouldn't have this used by the `state` package you wouldn't need to reorganize anything

Comment: Basically, STRING is just a placeholder here for maintaining the simplicity. They are actually multiple structures. Actually, if there are no ways our then this would be the last resort which requires me to seek approvals from multiple reviewers after presenting the detailed analysis which I am trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: one other thing you could do is in your interface instead of returning `state.CollectionByCollectionName` return a new interface and for example if you after calling the search you only need the collection name this interface could have just a function called `GetCollectionName() string` and implement this function on your model, then you decouple your `type Search interface` from the `state` pkg

Comment: If you have a cyclic dependency, there are only 2 places to put the types. They either belong in the same package, or you use a 3rd shared package to store the shared types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by moving the Search interface to a new separate package 'search'.

Thank you all for helping me in this.

Thanks and Regards,
Prafulla.

Answer (score 2):

To break the dependency cycle move `type STRING string` into the `state` package (as that's only place where it is used - so I guess it is related to it) and remove `model` import from `state` package. Alternatively, if it does not fit there logically move `type STRING string` into its own third package and only import that in the `state` package.

NOTE: I assume type `STRING` is just placeholder for something more meaningful to keep your example simple. There's no point in having `type STRING string` at all. If you remove it and just use `string` you no longer need to import `model` in `state`.

Comment: Yes, you are right regarding the note. STRING is just the placeholder here and in reality they are multiple structures with some meaning.Actually, if there are no ways our then this would be the last resort which requires me to seek approvals from multiple reviewers after presenting the detailed analysis which I am trying to avoid if possible.